# Is there a way for C# ASP.NET Web API to stream progress from server side?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm working with an ASP.NET Web API. I have a requirement in which I need to monitor the progress of streaming from the Server side code

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\largefile.tmp", File.Open, .....)
var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Content = new StreamContent(fs,8192)
};
```

What I did is create a class that inherits the `Stream` and override the `Read` method that will monitor on  progress of streaming.

```
public class FileStreamX : Stream
{
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
         /// Progress reading logic here..
    } 
}
```

But it seems this is a long way.

Is there any way to read the progress of streaming from server side?

Comment: This can be also used:

https://gist.github.com/scattered-code/e8c221058d63cfbce3dda867be4707bb